# Why there is no request and response in firebug--net--html?

Tags: html, http, request, response

The simple html file put into /var/www/html/test1.html.
The file bird.mp4 was saved as /var/www/html/bird.mp4.

```
<html>
<p>it is a test</p>
<video src="bird.mp4"  autoplay controls="controls">
</vedio>
</html>
```

Why there is no request ,no response, nothing in firebug--net--html when to click play button?

[image: no request ,no response, nothing]

There are so many requests and responses in firebug--net--html when to play a vedio on web.

[image: so many requests and responses]

And no packages captured by tcpdump when to play the video on my webpage.
The video size is about 9M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you clicked "HTML" and not "All" or "Media" in the filter tabs, and the video isn't an HTML document.

[image]

Comment: Why no packages captured by tcpdump when to play the video on my webpage.

Comment: Speculation: Because it is cached

Answer (score 0):

To click  firebug--net--media.